# After building in Unity, the shaders that apply to the render list disappear

Tags: unity-game-engine, build, urp, shader-graph

[image]

In Editor, no problem. However, After build, the shader disappeared. How can I solve this problem?

I included it in the **always included shader** but the results are the same.

Platform is Android.

Comment: What platform are you building for?

Comment: Platform is Android

Comment: Maybe the shader is not compatible with android.. can you try to build for windows platform?